# Unable to sort NSMutableDictionary [Objective C]

Tags: objective-c

I populate an `NSMutableDictionary` with some Json, the problem is that even if the Json is ordered correctly the `NSMutableDictionary` reorder the values randomly (at least I don't know what's the logic behind it).

I tried to reorder the `NSMutableDictionary` using the following method but I still get the same result as the Json:

```
NSArray* sortedKeys = [theData allKeys];
NSMutableArray* orderHelper = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:sortedKeys];
[orderHelper sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *str1, NSString *str2) {
    return [str1 compare:str2 options:(NSNumericSearch)];
}];

NSMutableDictionary *sortedDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (NSString *key in orderHelper){
    [sortedDictionary setObject:theData[key] forKey:key];
}
```

where `theData` is the first `NSMutableDictionary` containing the Json.

debugging I can see that the `NSMutableArray` gets ordered correctly but then on the for the `NSMutableArray` randomly reorders the items.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered; if you want to preserve the insertion order, you have to use some kind of special OrderedDictionary. There is none in the standard objc library, but there are open source implementations available.

Comment: Normally you'd have an array of dictionary keys and sort that by dictionary key or value.

Comment: You may also tell us what you need an ordered `NSDictionary`, and maybe we can help with that!

Comment: @Leo oh damn ok.. but what's the logic behind it's own reorder method?

Comment: I need to order the key value that is an NSString (the order function i've used works correctly, the problem is that after assigning it again to the NSMutableDictionary the values doesn't keep the order)

Comment: The method is not of public domain and you cannot guarantee any given order or logic whatsoever

Comment: @Signo not sure which method you are talking about; there is no public `reorder` method

Comment: @Leo sorry, I mean how does the NSMutableDictionary decide what's the order of the elements inside it?

Comment: You cannot order a dictionary. But you've got the orderHelper Array already. Why don't you just go from there?

Comment: @Signo I've now turned my comment into an answer and tried to address that question as well ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries (or Maps) are generally not an ordered data structure, and this is also the case for `NSDictionary` and the like. That means that the iteration order of your dictionary or the order of the `allKeys` array does not correspond to the insertion order of the associations you put into the dictionary.

So since the order is important to you, you have two options:

1) Use an `OrderedDictionary` implementation which does exactly that (preserve insertion order). There is none in the Objective-C standard library, but open-source alternatives are available.

2) Keep track of the order yourself in a separate `NSArray` in which you put the keys of your dictionary. Then, instead of iterating over your dictionary directly, you iterate over this array and read the corresponding values from the dictionary.

The internal order of a dictionary is entirely implementation-specific and of no value to you, since it might even be subject to changes. But very easily put, you can think about it the following way: The dictionary will assign a numerical value to each of your keys (e.g. `foo` is mapped to `0` and `bar` to `1`. When you insert this key, it will add the value to a bucket at the corresponding numerical index. So regardless of the insertion order, `foo` will always end up in the first bucket, and `bar` will always end up in the second bucket. This is the order you can observe when subsequently iterating the dictionary.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation :) I've ended up using a separate NSArray